# How successful is hypnosis or hypnotherapy over a distance, for example, over Skype?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, hypnosis

Some hypnotherapists offer healings over the internet, whereas some other don't. I'd like to know how successful is hypnosis or hypnotherapy over a distance, for example, over Skype?

Answer (score 4):

A literature review was conducted [Barak et al. (2008)](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Meyran_Boniel-Nissim/publication/237739176_A_Comprehensive_Review_and_a_Meta-Analysis_of_the_Effectiveness_of_Internet-Based_Psychotherapeutic_Interventions/links/54ae40c10cf2828b29fcc7a1.pdf) that compared the effectiveness of internet-based psychotherapy in general (not specifically hypnosis). From their abstract, the results indicate that:

> The overall mean weighted **effect size** was found to be 0.53 (medium effect),
>   which **is quite similar to the average effect size of traditional, face-to-face
>   therapy**.

Following, they

> [...] examined interacting effects of various possible relevant moderators of the effects of online therapy, including type of therapy [...], type of outcome measure, time of measurement of outcome (post-therapy or follow-up), type of problem treated, therapeutic approach, and communication modality,
>   among others. **A comparison between face-to-face and Internet intervention
>   as reported on in 14 of the studies revealed no differences in
>   effectiveness**.

In short, the studies reviewed,

> provide **strong support for the adoption of online psychological
>   interventions as a legitimate therapeutic activity** [...].

Comment: Does the review deal with hypnosis? I skimmed through it but did not find a mention of it

Comment: @lucianopaz I am not sure it does specifically. I believe the results may be generalizable given that they found no differences even when correcting for type of therapy